# Confused by definition of left Kan extension

Tags: category-theory, kan-extensions

I'm struggling to reconcile two definitions of the left Kan extension.

Suppose:

- $C$ is a discrete category with two objects $c_1,c_2$
- $D$ is a category with two objects $d_1,d_2$ and one non-identity morphism $f: d_2 \rightarrow d_1$
- $F: C \rightarrow Set$ is a functor that maps $F(c_1) = \{x_1\}, F(c_2) = \{y_1,y_2\}$
- $K: C \rightarrow D$ is a functor that maps $K(c_1) = d_1, K(c_2) = d_2$

I'm looking to find the left Kan extension of $F$ along $K$. From Riehl's Category Theory with Context we can use the following definition since $Set$ is co-complete
[image]

To evaluate $Lan_KF(d_1)$ we can see that the category $(K \downarrow d_1)$ has two objects:
$$(c_1, id_{d_1}: d_1 \rightarrow d_1), (c_2, f: d_2 \rightarrow d_1)$$
Since $C$ is discrete there are no morphisms between these objects. Therefore this colimit is simply the coproduct of $F(c_1)$ and $F(c_2)$, which suggests that $Lan_KF(d_1) = F(c_1) + F(c_2) = \{x_1, y_1, y_2\}$.

However, I don't see how this makes sense by the following definition:
[image]

It seems like we can define a functor $M: D \rightarrow Set$
\begin{align*}
&M(d_1) = \{x_1\}\\
&M(d_2) = \{y_1, y_2\}\\
&M(f)(y_1) = x_1, M(f)(y_2) = x_1
\end{align*}
and identity natural transformation $\gamma: F \rightarrow (M \circ K)$ since:
\begin{align*}
&(M \circ K)(c_1) = F(c_1) = \{x_1\}\\
&(M \circ K)(c_2) = F(c_2) = \{y_1, y_2\}
\end{align*}

How is $M$ not the left Kan extension? What am I missing?

Comment: Riehl’s definition is stronger and usually known as “pointwise left Kan extension”. The problem is that your proposed solution is not universal.

Comment: Hi @ZhenLin, thanks for the response! Given that Set is co-complete, isn't the pointwise left Kan extension going to be equivalent to the left Kan extension in general? Can you elaborate a bit on why $M, \gamma$ is not universal? It seems that $\eta$ are defined should factor through $\gamma$ since the components of $\gamma$ is the identity. I'm clearly missing something important, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Zhen Lin points out, your definition is not initial. Consider natural transformations $φ : M → \mathsf{Lan}_K F$, where the latter is given by the point-wise definition. This requires:

$$
φ_{d_1} : \{x_1\} → \{x_1,y_1,y_2\} \\
φ_{d_2} : \{y_1,y_2\} → \{y_1,y_2\}
$$

such that:

$$
φ_{d_1} \circ M(f) = \mathsf{Lan}_K F(f) \circ φ_{d_2}
$$

noting that $\mathsf{Lan}_KF(f)$ is effectively the inclusion of $\{y_1,y_2\}$ into $\{x_1,y_1,y_2\}$. The left hand side of the equation is just a constant function yielding whatever $φ_{d_1}$ picks out. Because of the behavior of $\mathsf{Lan}_KF$, the constant must be either $y_1$ or $y_2$. And $φ_{d_2}$ must also be a constant map to this value. However, this means there are two valid definitions of $φ$, so $M$ is not initial.